# xcode I want my app to be located in the middle in any devices

Tags: xcode, autolayout

[image]

I am making app for IPhone.

When it is opened at Ipad, it is appeared as figure 1.

But I want to modify this as figure 2.

I have tried to use set center vertically and horizontally in Container, but it doesn't work.

How can i do it?

Comment: are you adding your views in code?

Comment: I'm new in xcode. so I don't know about view... Do i have to add view?

Comment: Are you using a storyboard or are you adding your views programmatically?

Comment: I used storyboard. Do I have to add views?

Comment: No, it should work with storyboards. On the bottom of your Editor Area, left of the constraints editors, there's a "View as:" option, play around with that and watch how your view changes on different device sizes. If you see the same behavior as you are seeing now then you probably added your constraints for specific device screen size.

Comment: I have made another new view and put all things to the view. Thanks for replying!